# How to calculate DateDiff in minutes correctly?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find a way to calculate minutes between 2 times using DATEDIFF

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, CAST('05:00:00' AS time), CAST('23:59:00' AS time))
```

This returns 1139 which is correct but when I do

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, CAST('05:00:00' AS time), CAST('00:37:00' AS time))
```

I get -263.

I have different data with different end dates in my database, and my question is how can I use single query to calculate the minutes correctly for both the cases?

Comment: You should combine date and time to make complete datetime bits and then subtract.  What are your column names? what is your RDBMS?

Comment: It's SQL server and column names are start_date_time and end_date_time. Both are datetime type

Comment: if the date parts of those are populated, and if end_date_time is greater than start-date_time, and you use datediff(minute, start_date_time, end_date_time) it will be positive, I don't understand the problem; why do you only use the time parts?

Comment: @tinazmu I'm calculating the duration in minutes between start and end date. 

For ex: 

1. Today, 23/11/2022 - 5:00 AM to 23:59 PM is 18 hours 59 minutes ~ 1,139 minutes
2. Today 23/11/2022 - 5:00 AM to 00:37 (24/11/2022) is 19 hours, 37 minutes ~ 1,177 minutes

I can get the first result using my query, but not the second result as it is exceeding one day.

Comment: How do you expect the engine to know that you mean 23/Nov or 24/Nov? In this case the time is not the only parameter you need, because between 5AM to Midnight at the same day - it is "negative" time

Answer (score 3):

There is no issue in this case.
5 AM is after Midnight (and 37 minutes).
Every day starts at 00:00:00.000 and ends up at 23:59:59.999.

Because you specified only the time, it cannot understand that you need the day after.

I suggest you to specify the date as well:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, CAST('2022-11-22 05:00:00' AS datetime), CAST('2022-11-23 00:37:00.000' AS datetime))
```